# CodeIgniter shows old page after new FTP upload

Tags: php, codeigniter, ftp

I have been trying to upload new pages to a CodeIgniter-based website, but I noticed that the new pages are not accessible. Instead, I'm getting a 301 error loop (since the controller redirects me to a non-existing page, apparently).

Changing existing pages and uploading them also does not work. The changes I made are not visible on the website. The changed files have been successfully uploaded to the server through FTP, although this is not reflected in the website when I browse it. I figured it might be a cache problem, but this does not seem to be the case. Any ideas?

Comment: You might not be in the right root directory and/or file permissions need reset.

Comment: The thing is, everything worked before and there have not been any changes to server settings that I'm aware of. So a wrong root directory can be ruled out, I'd say. I'm not sure about the file permissions. How could those have changed and what does it have to do with the current issue? Thanks.